# R: Count of unique values within group

Tags: r, data.table

Update:

I have the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(clause = c("Hello world my dearest","Hello world my dearest","Hello world my dearest","Hello world my dearest","Hello world my dearest","Hello world my dearest"),
                 word = c("Hello", "Hello", "world", "my", "dearest", "dearest"),
                 syllable = c("He", "lo", "world", "my", "dea", "rest"),
                 phrase_ID = c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2"))
```

This basically shows the syntax of the clause "hello world, my dearest", consisting of
2 phrases, 4 words, and 6 syllables.
The phrases are only indicated by a phrase_ID though.

I did the following conversion to get the position and total number of syllables
in the word and the phrase.

```
setDT(df)[, word_ID := rleid(word, phrase_ID)]
df[, poss_syll_in_word := sequence(.N), by = word_ID]
```

What I now want to do is to do the same conversion for position and number of 
words in phrase and words in clause:

```
df$poss_word_in_phrase <- c("1", "1", "2", "1", "2", "2")
df$n_word_in_phrase <- c("2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2")
```

I can't get find a solution. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

Based on updated data , I guess we can use `data.table::rleid` and `n_distinct` to get the expected output.

In `data.table`

```
df[, c("poss_word_in_phrase", "n_word_in_phrase") := 
            list(rleid(word_ID), uniqueN(word_ID)), phrase_ID]
```

Or with `dplyr`

```
df %>%
  group_by(phrase_ID) %>%
  mutate(poss_word_in_phrase = data.table::rleid(word_ID), 
         n_word_in_phrase = n_distinct(word_ID))
```

---

Using `tidyverse`, we can split the string at every word to find out it's position in `word` and use `str_count` to count number of words.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(poss_word_in_phrase = map2_dbl(str_split(phrase, "\\s+"), word, 
                               ~match(.y, .x)), 
         n_word_in_phrase = str_count(phrase, "\\w+"), 
         poss_word_in_clause = map2_dbl(str_split(clause, "\\s+"), word, 
                               ~match(.y, .x)),
         n_word_in_clause =  str_count(clause, "\\w+"))

#                     clause      phrase    word syllable poss_word_in_phrase
#1 Hello world my dearest Hello world   Hello       He                   1
#2 Hello world my dearest Hello world   Hello       lo                   1
#3 Hello world my dearest Hello world   world    world                   2
#4 Hello world my dearest  my dearest      my       my                   1
#5 Hello world my dearest  my dearest dearest      dea                   2
#6 Hello world my dearest  my dearest dearest     rest                   2

#  n_word_in_phrase poss_word_in_clause n_word_in_clause
#1                2                   1                4
#2                2                   1                4
#3                2                   2                4
#4                2                   3                4
#5                2                   4                4
#6                2                   4                4
```

**data**

I corrected your input data a bit by assuming in `clause` column you meant `"world"` instead of `"word"`.

```
df <- data.frame(clause = c("Hello world my dearest","Hello world my dearest",
    "Hello world my dearest","Hello world my dearest",
    "Hello world my dearest","Hello world my dearest"),
    phrase = c("Hello world", "Hello world", "Hello world", "my dearest", 
     "my dearest", "my dearest"),
    word =  c("Hello", "Hello", "world", "my", "dearest", "dearest"),
    syllable = c("He", "lo", "world", "my", "dea", "rest"))
```

Comment: thx for the solution. That works fine. 
I realized I had to update the sample data though. 
Your solution works only if I have a phrase column.
In fact, I realized I don't have the phrase column but  only phrase_IDs that group words into the phrases.

Comment: @IskandarThePupsi How do you define phrases from `clause` ? Do you consider every group of two words as one phrase ? What is the logic to count `poss_word_in_phrase` ?

Comment: I optain this on the basis of a previously done annotation; so in that way it can be 12 or 2 words, which from the dataframe seems an arbitrary choice. 
The logic into countin ```poss_word_in_phrase``` is to count within each group of ```phrase_ID``` the number of words it comprises, based on the  ```word_ID``` column. So every word will get a position and if the word has 4 syllables (e.g. 4 rows) each row belongin to one word will have the same value for ```poss_word_in_phrase``` <-- does that make sense?

Comment: @IskandarThePupsi I don't see `word_ID` column in the data you have shared. Have you forgotten to include that ? Also can you explain why the output `poss_word_in_phrase` is 2 for 3rd row ?

Comment: the ```word_ID``` is created here ```setDT(df)[, word_ID := rleid(word, phrase_ID)]``` 
The output is 2 for 3rd row because the ```phrase_ID == 1``` indicating that all the rows belong to group 1. Looking at ```word_ID``` then shows that the  ```phrase_ID == 1``` comprises two words with the ```word_ID == 1 ``` ```word_ID == 2 ``` . So for every word ID, I need the equivalent position. ```poss_word_in_phrase``` is hence 2 for 3rd row because it is the second word within the phrase with ```phrase_ID == 1```

Comment: @IskandarThePupsi Can you check my updated answer to confirm if that is what you want ?